# GNU make automatically deletes precompiled header

Tags: gcc, gnu-make, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to get a precompiled header to speed up my build using gmake and GCC. The `.gch` file is created, but for some reason it's automatically removed as soon as the build completes.

Here are the relevant rules:

```
cxx_pch := ./bin/analysis.h.gch

bin/%.cpp.o: src/%.cpp $(cxx_includes) $(cxx_pch)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(cxx_include_paths) -H -c -o $@ $<

bin/%.gch: src/pch/%
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(cxx_include_paths) -I./src -x c++-header -o $@ $<
```

The last thing printed when I build is this:

```
rm bin/analysis.h.gch
```

None of my rules could possibly do this; `clean` only does `rm -r $(output_dir)`.

Comment: And, when you use `make -d`, what do you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark it as `.PRECIOUS:` or `.SECONDARY:` to prevent Make from cleaning it up as an intermediate target.  See also http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html

Comment: That did the trick. Sorry for the delay, I would have accepted this a few minutes ago but had to wait for the build :vP